# Copy a complete form with jquery from an Iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe

we need to use an Iframe do display our forms (its a web tool for forms).
Is it possible to copy the hole form out of the Iframe and paste it into the normal page with javascript, so that we can submit the form from there?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since your iframe is loading from a different domain, you cannot do this.  Your best bet to accomplish this would be to create a proxy that would load the iframe content on the server and then pass the content to your page.

Comment: our domain: www.mydomain.com
Iframe domain: www3.mydomain.com, could it work with that domain?

Comment: No, the domain needs to match, as far as I know.  Best bet would be to try it and see what you get